# Does $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 (\vec{r}_2 + \vec{r}_1 )} ?= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2(\vec{r}_2)} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2(\vec{r}_1)}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Is the following equation true?
$$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 (\vec{r}_2 + \vec{r}_1 )} ?= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2(\vec{r}_2)}  + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2(\vec{r}_1)} ?$$
If not, what is the left side equal to?
I think this question falls into the category of matrix calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the bijective change $\begin{cases} u=x+y\\v=x-y\end{cases}$

Then you have to apply the chain rule to $f(x,y)=f(\frac{u+v}2,\frac{u-v}2)$

So you get

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u}=\dfrac 12(f'_x+f'_y)$

$\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2}=\cdots=\dfrac 14(f''_{xx}+2f''_{xy}+f''_{yy})$

Comment: Thank you. Which topic should I study to learn more about this?

Comment: I don't know, personally I didn't had the occasion to play too much with partial differentials in my studies. Till you know the chain rule, Green and Ostrogradsky formulas you cover much of the stuff. There are more complicated objects like the Jacobian or the Hessian, but in the end it's just repeated use of the chain rule. Maybe if you go for differential geometry, PDE or thermodynamics you'll have to use it more. Hum, yes I forgot, cylindrical and spherical change of variable differentials are also largely used, you may want to have a look at that.

Comment: Thank you! I have just recently come across the Jacobian. I remember studying that in multivariable calculus...